# Помогите с пунктуацией в данных примерах

Tags: пунктуация, орфография

1) Почему, когда долго сидишь за компьютером, слипаются глаза?

2) Почему, если долго сидеть за компьютером, слипаются глаза?

3) Почему, когда бросаешь курить, толстеешь?

(Ошибки есть? Тире нигде не нужно поставить?)

Answer (score 2):

Оформление правильное, это СПП, придаточное предложение находится внутри главного после вопросительного местоимения.